what could be wrong as to why drawing ellipse does not work in miktex 2.8
Ok i searched the internet and it spoke of a simple addition to miktex, i have miktex2.8, to draw an ellipse without having to use the big additions such as tkiz or whatever but a much smaller addition to pic2e which i already have in miktex. so i found what i thought were the 2 pertinent files ellipse.ins and ellipse.dtx and put them in c\miktex2.8\tpm\packages directory and it still did not work. I would try to put in a hyperlink but it would not work because what i read on the internet does not have any link nor http\ anything like that. So what am i doing wrong and/or how do i install that small addition to pic2e in miktex2.8 so i can draw an ellipse.

that post was not accepting any questions or comments etc. and this is also enough different than that. i no longer need how to draw it inside a circle etc.

ellipse.dtx and ellipse.ins are docstrip files. You need to run tex ellipse.ins or latex ellipse.ins to generate ellipse.sty. Afterwards you can use \usepackage{ellipse} in your document.

https://ctan.org/pkg/ellipse is packaged by MiKTeX and installs through the console straightforwardly on a current MiKTeX installation (I believe MiKTeX 2.8 was superseded by MiKTeX 2.9 more than a decade ago).

it has been remarked on the internet miktex 2.9 does not work.

You do not need to install anything manually. ellipse is part of miktex and either is already installed or can be installed with the miktex console. This works fine for me
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter 
\newdimen\@tempdimd %fix bug in ellipse
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor,ellipse}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{10pt}%
\begin{picture}(6,8)
\linethickness{0.8pt}%
\put(6,3){\color{teal}\ellipse*{2}{3}}%
\put(3,3){\color{blue}\ellipse{3}{2}}%
\end{picture}

\end{document}



You are too early, first christmas, than easter holidays!

when you say can be installed using miktex console what do u mean ? what is the miktex console ? where u wrote \usepackage(xcolor,ellipse) does that mean i have to have some special something like a file named usepackage(xcolor,ellipse)? what if i don't have it then what ?

https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console. And if you want to know what happens: try it out.
